# Doctrine 1.4: Запрос с результатом - массивом с объектами

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
public function getCompanies($arr){
        $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('')
            ->from('Compania')
            ->whereIn('id',$arr)
            ->fetchArray();
    }
```

Результат будет массивом с элементами таблицы Compania. Мне нужно, чтобы результат был массивом с объектами таблицы Compania.

Запрос вида:

```
$query = Doctrine_Core::getTables('Compania')-> ???
```

Такой запрос вернет объекты, но не могу засунуть в него условие

> whereIn

которое принимает в качестве параметра массив значений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Compania')->createQuery()->whereIn('id', $result_keys)->execute();
```